# Numpy invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

```
import numpy as np
fx = np.zeros([6])
fy = np.zeros([6])
ax = np.zeros([6])
ay = np.zeros([6])
x = np.zeros([6])
y = np.zeros([6])
vy = np.zeros([6])
vx = np.zeros([6])
x[0] = 11
x[1] = 13
x[2] = 10
x[3] = 6
x[4] = 5
x[5]= 7.1
vx[0] = 1
vy[0] = 1
y[0] = 1
y[1] = 2
y[2] = 4
y[3] = 6
y[4] = 5
y[5]= 7.1
sigma = 1.01
e = 1.1
dt = 0.1
def LJ(x,y):
    for i in range(0,6):
        for j in range(0,6):
            if i == j:
                continue
            rx = x[i]-x[j]
            ry = y[i]-y[j]
            fx[i] = 24*e*(((2/rx)*sigma/rx**12)-((1/rx)*sigma/rx**6))
            fy[i] = 24*e*(((2/ry)*sigma/ry**12)-((1/ry)*sigma/ry**6))
    return fx, fy

def verlet():
    for i in range(0,10):
        ax[i], ay[i] = -LJ(x[i],y[i])
        x[i+1] = x[i] + dt*vx[i]+0.5*dt**2*ax[i]
        y[i+1] = y[i] + dt*vy[i]+0.5*dt**2*ay[i]
        ax[i+1],ay[i+1] = -LJ(x[i+1],y[i+1])
        vx[i+1] = vx[i] + 0.5*dt*(ax[i]+ax[i+1])
        vy[i+1] = vy[i] + 0.5*dt*(ay[i]+ay[i+1])
        t[i+1] = t[i]+dt
        print x,y

verlet()
```

I tried to use verlet alghoritm to calculate forces, positions, velocities and accelerations.
When I start my program I get error

```
     ax[i], ay[i] = LJ(x[i],y[i])
    rx = x[i]-x[j]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I do not understand that error. What is wrong?? Is my verlet alghoritm correct?

Comment: I tried without minus but it didnt help

Comment: Check your traceback. The problem is `rx = x[i]-x[j]`. x is an integer. I think you meant to pass `x` and `y` and not `x[i],y[i]` to LJ? There are lots of software packages out there btw for calculating Lennard Jones potentials...

Comment: in `LJ(x[i],y[i])` are you trying to pass a matrix/list or an element ?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I changed that and i am getting error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.' I know there is a software for calculating Lennard Jones potentials but I want to create simulation of moving particles in 2D in Python.

Comment: @cmidi element of array

Comment: What have you tried to solve this next error message yourself? The traceback tells you, which line is causing the problem.

Comment: I removed indexes `i` and `j` but now I have wrong results śo I think those indexes are needed here.

Comment: Your original question was answered.